# Elastic Search full import

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

We use Elastic Search in our project and we follow the push approach.
We have a scheduler that runs at every 30 mins and reads data from the tables and push the same to Elastic Search using Spring Data Elastic Search.

```
Collection<ElasticSearchIndexObj> indexObjs = new ArrayList<>();

Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();

            stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            stmt.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);          
            rs =  stmt.executeQuery(ESEARCH_FULL_IMPORT_QUERY);

            int i=1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                ElasticSearchIndexObj indexObj = new ElasticSearchIndexObj();
                indexObj.setName("Raja");


                indexObjs .add(indexObj);

                if (i % FETCH_SIZE == 0) {
                    elasticSearchObjIndexRepository.save(indexObjs);
                    indexObjs.clear();
                }               
                i=i+1;
            }           
            elasticSearchSecurityIndexRepository.save(indexObjs);
            indexObjs.clear();
```

We do read the whole table and insert into elastic search every 30 mins to keep the index data in sync with tables. The table is being owned by some other team.

Doubt :- Rows were deleted from the table. Now, when i do select *, i will not be getting the deleted records. but, those records still there in the elastic search and these records will become stale data in the search. How can i delete all the records in the elastic search before inserting as part of the schedule without affecting the search in the front screen.

Is there anyway I can use transaction here, so that i will do delete all, save and finally commit.

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 2):

You can delete index by using delete API of elastic search.

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index_name
```

For deleting all indexes you can use * or _all.
For using same thing in java you have to execute this query

```
DeleteResponse response = client.prepareDelete().execute().actionGet();
```

Regards